# Hadoop Hive: In Hive how we can store/load .ods file

Tags: hadoop, hive

In Hive as we can store or load text file as 'STORE AS TEXTFILE', but how we can store or load .ods file.

Here I have stored the .ods file as textfile but while fetching it gives in some different kind of as machine language.

Pleas  any one help me in it how we can load .ods file in hive.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "stored the .ods file as textfile?" If you open the .ods file in an editor (such as nano or vim) does it display as plaintext?

Comment: No, it displaying in some different machine language. due this I am in trouble.

Comment: Sounds like you have simply changed the extension and did not actually convert the file to txt format. Googling "convert ods to txt" yields some helpful results.